# How to transform Different timezone

Tags: coldfusion, timezone, coldfusion-11

I'm using

[TimeZone-CFC](https://github.com/rip747/TimeZone-CFC)

How do you transform

- PT to PST or PDT
- MT to MST or MDT
- CT to CST or CDT
- ET to EST or EDT

I've checked the list of TimeZone but PT,MT,CT and ET are not in the timezone list.

I was thinking I can map the PT,MT,CT,ET like:

```
<!--- use Pacific time as sample --->
<cfset varTimeZone = "PT">

<cfif varTimeZone is "PT">
    <cfset useTZ = "US/Pacific">
<cfelseif varTimeZone is "ET">  
    <cfset useTZ = "US/Eastern">
<cfelseif varTimeZone is "CT">  
    <cfset useTZ = "US/Central">
<cfelseif varTimeZone is "MT">
    <cfset useTZ = "US/Mountain">       
</cfif>


<cfdump var="#application.tz.castFromUTC(utcDate,useTZ)#">
```

If I have a date like "2017-10-25 03:41:29.000" which is in UTC. I will need to display it in PST.

Another one to consider is the server uses "America/New_York" timezone. To get server timezone:

```
<!--- server timezone --->
<cfset tz = CreateObject("java", "java.util.TimeZone")>
<cfset tz = tz.getDefault()>
<cfoutput>TimeZone: #tz.getDisplayName()# (#tz.getID()#)</cfoutput>
```

If the server is in UTC it would have been easier.

Comment: I don't believe PT, MT, CT or ET are actually time zones. They are used to reference the currently observed time (either standard time or daylight time). So depending on the time of year they will equal PST, MST, CST, EST or PDT, MDT, CDT, EDT.

Comment: How are you using TimeZone-CFC? It relies on the underlying Java to check a Timezone and whether or not it is in Daylight Time. But I'm guessing this would also depend quite a bit on how it was that you're storing dates. It can get a bit tricky. Which is why it's usually better to store dates in UTC and then just convert on the display end, as needed.  But back to your issue, where do you see PT/MT/CT/ET? And do you account for areas like Arizona or Indianapolis who don't follow DST (though I guess TimeZone-CFC would do that)?

Comment: And what version of CF are you using? Can you provide us with a sample of the data you are working with?

Comment: Timezone-CFC have isDST function which can determine if daylight saving time is observed.

Comment: @shawn 
Running in Coldfusion 11. 

The current setup in our system uses PT, MT, CT or ET I don't have the luxury to use the usual Timezones like PST etc.

Comment: Where is PT/MT/CT/ET coming from? Can you provide an example of the date string you're working with? And is it a string or a date object?